# I suspect vim-ros plugin is not working appropriately

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all.
I just installed the vim plugin [vim-ros](https://github.com/taketwo/vim-ros) but I fell it is not working or at least not appropriately. Well, after its installation a source file from some ROS package and tried the commands **:A**, **:Roscd** and **:Rosed** and none of them worked. In fact the following message is printed by vim:

> E492: Not an editor command: A

So, I would like to know what am I missing to correctly configure the vim-ros plugin.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/249800/i-suspect-vim-ros-plugin-is-not-working-appropriately/) by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2016-12-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-11**:
I would report this on the [issue tracker](https://github.com/taketwo/vim-ros/issues) of `vim-ros`. That will probably lead to quicker resolution of your issues.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-11**:
Could [issues/18](https://github.com/taketwo/vim-ros/issues/18) be related?

**Comment by [Randerson](https://answers.ros.org/users/25441/randerson/) on 2016-12-11**:
thanks!!! I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For completeness, I'll post the answer here.

gvdhoorn was right; it was related to [issues/18](https://github.com/taketwo/vim-ros/issues/18). The fix is to install vim with Python 2.7 support:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-nox-py2
```

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2016-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0